# How to show bijection between bilinear forms and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Suppose we have a bilinear form:
$$T: V \times V \rightarrow F$$  and $\dim V = n < \infty $. We are to prove that there is a bijection between that bilinear form and set of matrices $M_n(F)$ if $n \in N$ ($M_n(F)$ means the linear space of all matrices $n \times n$ and $F = C$ or $F = R$).
I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: You should be able to show that the space of matrices and the space of bilinear forms are both vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, with the same dimension.

Comment: Why it would be enough? @Joppy

Comment: Because vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic, and that isomorphism must be a bijection.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks. Can you send me a link or something with a proof of this?